# rust and vec iterator - how to filter

Tags: rust

I have a vector and trying to create a new vector by filtering.  It does not work and I don't know why:

```
fn example(data: Vec<f64>, missing_value: f64) {
    let dude = data
        .iter()
        .filter(|&x| *x != missing_value)
        .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
}
```

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<f64>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&f64`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:10
  |
5 |         .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
  |          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<f64>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&f64>`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&f64>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<f64>`
```

Comment: add `.cloned()` before collect, and please this is not a good question at all.

Answer (score 10):

There is a single [implementation of `FromIterator` for `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E), and this implementation collects values of `T` from the same type `T`, i.e., it is not possible to convert `T` into an arbitrary type `U` and collect its elements at the same time.

In your case, you want to collect an iterator of `&f64` into a vector of `f64`, therefore, you need to convert by cloning/copying and then collect.

```
self.data.iter().filter(|&&x| x != self.missing_value).cloned().collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```

If you have ownership of the vector, it is possible to iterate over `f64` instead of `&f64` by using `into_iter`.

```
self.data.into_iter().filter(|&x| x != self.missing_value).collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9906ee9a4373bda1e47d82b755d41ad ?

Comment: You should use `retain` instead of `into_iter` + `filter` + `collect` if you are okay with consuming the `Vec`. Know your standard library!

Comment: Also, I'd put `cloned()` before `filter`, and avoid the double-borrow, but maybe that's just me.